# Working with JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am reading Rails guide and saw this

> Rails ships with CoffeeScript by default

OK. If that's the case why's it that when I generate a new rails app, in the javascript assets folder I get `application.js` and then when I generate a controller I get another file `controler_name.coffee`? What's the point in keeping 2 extensions and what's the reason they adopted CoffeeScript if not to, say, reduce code lines. Any benefit here?

Answer (score 1):

`application.js` is the manifest file, in which you tell Sprockets what Javascript files are to be loaded into your application. Read up on the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more details on how it works.

You can write your JS in `application.js` and it will run fine, but it's not a good idea as it might degenerate into a big ball of random JS as the app grows.

The `controller_name.coffee` files are where your actual application specific CoffeeScript should go, grouped to help you organize JS specific to each controller.

Note that JS/CS in any `controller_name.coffee` file loads for *all* pages by default.